# Queuing and priority?

Tags: multithreading, queue, priority-queue, beanstalkd

How can I avoid a queue (Beanstalk) to block other users if the initial one takes time ?

For example, if my first user upload a file that takes 10 hours to be processed, how can I avoid the other users to have to wait 10 hours to have their file started.

For the details : One user upload a file with n lines. This file will be splitted in small chuncks of 1000 lines and added to a queue. 4 worker works simultaneously to process the queue (which means 4000 lines at the same time).

If the first user upload a file containing 100.000 lines, and the second user upload a file of 4.000 lines, he will have to wait that the workers have finished processing the first file.

Is there a way to avoid forcing the second user to wait ?

The only solution that cames to my mind is to limit the number of lines to a certain amount (that will be not too long to wait) and if the file is higher, create a dedicated instance to that specific user.

How would you do?